# TFS - Azure File Copy task

Tags: azure, tfs, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy a file with Azure File Copy task in Team Foundation Server build.

These are my settings:

[image]

I get error when trying to build:
[image]

What exactly am I suppose to to here? I have connected my Azure account with Resource Manager and I just fill the name of storage account name.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing there is a problem with the way you hooked up your Azure Service Endpoint.  Did you use the script from here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/

Comment: I will check into this today and inform you

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue. As @rerwinRR mentionedin comment, after running the script, you would get the information below. Type these information in the `Azure Resource Manager` service Endpoint and try again.

```
Copy and Paste below values for Service Connection
***************************************************************************
Connection Name: xxxx(SPN)
Subscription Id: xxxxx
Subscription Name: xxxxx
Service Principal Id: xxxxx
Service Principal key: <Password that you typed in>
Tenant Id: xxxxx
***************************************************************************
```